# Magento 2: Guide for All Collections

Tags: magento2, collection, model, object-manager, documentation

For now, I'm not able to find any guide for this. If I need to get all collection say for Example all Orders List

so I will go to Vendor Magento Folder, Particular Module's `di.xml` file & checking one by one for the valid path, which can give me a result.

```
$objectManagerOrder = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollection = $objectManagerOrder->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection');
$orderCollection->load();
//echo $orderCollection->printlogquery(true);

foreach ($orderCollection as $orders) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $orders->getId();
}
```

So above will Print All Orders. **What i need is Orders with their All Items, Shipping & Billing Info of ordered Customers, Customer Detail, Payment Method, Shipping Method**. If i need to check for Order Customer then may be i need to use `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection`

So do we have any kind of list of all if go by Admin's List Sales, Products, Customers, Marketing, Content, Reports, Stores. Main Menu & All Sub Menus.

It will help if you need this use this path. Or any other method to bring all things.

It's gonna really helpful for development.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the default Magento 2 API.

For exemple, you can make a getList request to the vendor/magento/module-sales/Api/OrderRepositoryInterface.php

Check Rest/Soap API documentation and search criteria documentation here :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

This way, Magento 2 ensures backward compatibility with API.

Thanks,